# Slider and navbar in one

Tags: css

I have a problem in my css. I want to make my navbar like this ( as you can see, it has no background on navbar and it joins with slider ). I have tried every advice in youtube tutorials but nothing worked.

Here's the link I want to show you:
http://theme.ridianur.com/alamak/

I was able to change the color background of my navbar by opening bootstrap.min.css in notepad, search for "navbar-default", and change the color code. But, I wasn't able to make it no background like I want to.

My html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boot/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



        <title>Image Slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="kets.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid hero-slide">
        <div class="row">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Cats1">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="tekslide1">
            <h1>Hewan yang mainstream</h1>
            <p>Kita juga gatau kenapa milih topik kucing</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Cats2">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Cats3">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Cats4">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and my css :

```
@charset "utf-8";
    @font-face{
        font-family: 'custom';
        src: url('OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); //<-- semicolon
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: 'custom1';
        src: url('Alternate.ttf') format('truetype'); //<-- semicolon
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar .navbar-nav{
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
        font-family: 'custom';
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }

    .tekslide1{
        font-size: 25px;
        padding-left: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 500px;
        font-family: 'custom1';
    }
    .navbar .navbar-collapse{
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 120px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .nav >li >a { 
        color: #EEEEEE; 
        margin-left: 10px; 
        margin-right: 5px; 
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .nav >li >a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .nav >li >a:focus{
        color: #BDBDBD;
        background: none;
    }
    .logo{
        float: left;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 2px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
        margin-left: 5%;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }

    .hero-slide{
        margin-top: -20px;
    }

    .navbar li { color: #000 }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain this in pseudocode. If you want help you need include relevant bits of html and css in your post, not the archive of an entire site.

This effect you're looking for is nothing more than:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="navigation">

    </div>

    <div class="banner">

    </div>

</div>
```

and

```
.wrapper{background:url('your_image.jpg');}
.navigation, .banner{background:transparent;}
```

A graphic applied to a parent container and navigation / banner with transparent backgrounds.

Comment: I've edited the post. I confused which part i should change.